# Android default cut/copy/paste not showing in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am adding an EditText to the window using the WindowManager. However, long pressing the EditText does nothing. It selects the word I long pressed on, then immediately places cursor in front of said word. That is the only behavior experienced.

I have no code because its very straight forward. Simple layout, simple `windowManager.addView(myView, myParams);` method. How can I enable the long press stuff to work?

Comment: what is the `inputType` of your EditText?

Comment: `android:inputType="text|textAutoComplete|textMultiLine|textAutoCorrect"` so I am not sure what is the problem. I have a feeling it may be `context` related? The same exact layout works perfectly inside an activity.

Comment: @Seth did you find a solution? I'm facing the same issue with EditText inside a window. Whenever you select with long press, the word is highlighted and immediately deselected by its own... tried everything with no luck

Comment: @Shyri, yes I have. I wrote my own `EditText`, overrode the "onUp" event, thus canceling the default action (leaving the word(s) still selected) then showed my own "cut/copy/paste" menu along with clearing the selection.

Comment: @Seth, I've been trying to do that, and although what you say works, it still doesn't show the selection handles, at least in my case. Is it your case too or did you manage to show the handles?

Comment: @Shyri, you are correct. The selection handles do not show, in addition, only word selection works. This is "enough" for my purposes. More overriding would need to be done. Sadly, when using `editText.setSelection(start, end);` it does not select anything and only moves the cursor.

Comment: it doesn't work with Android 8 and above for my case, how bad it is!

Comment: **@Seth did you resolve this issue? I face this issue but it's so weird, somehow it relates to execute an AsyncTask inside the Activity/Fragment. I remove the AsyncTask and it work as normal. But it only happen with Android 8 and above**

Comment: @Seth so, you are using custom copy/paste menu? I'd like to show the system one, but I can't find how to do it.

Comment: @Den, yes I am. It is impossible to use the system one because the system one uses a "popupwindow" where it needs an activity type context to create. You can probably use the system layout but you need to inflate and show it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Place this inside the editText widget

```
android:textIsSelectable="true"
```

Or if you prefer programmatically

```
myEditText.setTextIsSelectable(true);
```

Also set

```
setfocusableintouchmode(true)
```

should also look into
[Copy and Paste](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html)

Comment: this does not work. It forces the editText no longer editable, but allows the text to be selected if entered programatically.

Comment: I'm sorry but none of this is relevant to my issue, nor does it solve it. I already am aware of the `ClipboardManager` which I will need to use if I have to create my own cut/copy/paste menu. But that is a totally different issue. I want the default stock android menu to show when long pressed.

Comment: No. Nothing is being overrode. I think the problem lies with the context that is being used to create the popup window for the default menu. I have watched the logcat and it tries to create it but is never created. I can easily create my own, but not sure how create the handles to select the text with.

And yes its not relevant. `EditText` by default has `testIsSelectable` and by adding it myself, disables the `editText` all together. The problem lies with the popup window, not the editText as i said it works in an activity.